# Renaming images downloaded by python

Tags: python-3.x

I've this following code that downloads multiple images from different URL. The code also renames the files assigning a random number between 1 and 1000 calculated by

```
random.randrange(1,1000)
```

Insted I'd like the code to rename the files assigning ordered numbers e.g. 1,2,3,4 
How can I modify the code?

```
import urllib.request
import random

def download_image(url):

    name=random.randrange(1,1000)
    fullname=str(name)+".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,fullname)

download_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/D%C3%BClmen%2C_Kirchspiel%2C_Erdbeerfeld_--_2015_--_6492-6.jpg")
download_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/StAngelo_Bridge_Rome.jpg")
```

Comment: You need to give examples of what you tried. This is not a site where people will solve your problems for you.

Comment: With a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a int variable which says which number it is. For example

```
 numImage = 0 #The int that will determine the name
 def download_image(url):

     name = str(numImage + 1) #The actual name
     if name == "1000": #Making sure it doesn't exceed 1000 as you said
         print("Max images exceeded!")
     else:

         fullname = name + ".jpg"
         urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,fullname)
         print("Saved as %s" % fullname) #Telling the user what it did.
```